# Django merge two QuerySets

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to merge these two QuerySets. HotkeyAndPrefix do not have entries for every Collection in all_collections. This means len(all_collections) >= len(all_collections_hotkeys_and_prefixes). How can i merge these two QuerySets? If there is no entrie found for a Collection in HotkeyAndPrefix I want hotkey = None, prefix=None. Can I achieve this in one query?

**models.py:**

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class HotkeyAndPrefix(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    assigned_collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, null=True)
    hotkey = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'assigned_collection')
```

**view.py**

```
admin = User.objects.filter(username='admin')[0]
all_collections = Collection.objects.filter(creator=admin)
current_user = request.user
all_collections_hotkeys_and_prefixes = HotkeyAndPrefix.objects.filter(assigned_collection__in=all_collections, user=current_user)
```

Comment: what should be the value of `user` for the `Collection`entries not in `HotkeyAndPrefix` ?

Comment: It is the value from the person(admin) who created the collection. admin = User.objects.filter(username='admin')[0]

Comment: How do you plan to merge two queryset of different types of objects? And what new information would that merge give?

Comment: I want to output all_collections in a table and if the current user has defined a hotkey/prefix for a collection I want to ouput it in the same table row.

Comment: I think for this what you can do is ouput two set one of collection for which a user has hotkey/prefix and another for which the user doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) query. You can take the list of values which are in the 
`HotkeyAndPrefix.objects.filter(assigned_collection__in=all_collections, user=current_user)` queryset

using

`all_collections_hotkeys_and_prefixes_values = all_collections_hotkeys_and_prefixes.values_list('assigned_collection',flat=True)`

and you can filter out the value, not in the `all_collections_hotkeys_and_prefixes_values` with one more query

`all_collections_hotkeys_and_prefixes_excluded = all_collections.exclude(pk__in=all_collections_hotkeys_and_prefixes_values)`

now you have two querysets, one of collection for which a user has hotkey/prefix and another for which the user doesn't